# How to preserve image path in Sikuli-IDE?

Tags: sikuli

I want to group my screenshots by their functional areas. In my BundlePath, I create folders of each of the functional areas and put screenshots in there.

For example: wait("student_nav/my_studies_tab.png")

I can save that and it runs just fine.

However, if I close and restart the IDE, the path to the image gets lost and only the filename remains.

That is: wait("my_studies_tab.png")

Even stranger, the .py files associated with the bundle retains the path until I close down the IDE for a second time. Then all of the paths are lost in the .py file as well.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but as a workaround may be you can store the image path in a variable and pass it to any function